# how to make background 100% on a top menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a *top menu* which should be 100% filled with `background-color` and also keep the content of my menu inside my wrap id which 960px.

Can somebody explain me how to do it.

Demo: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NnCVv/246)

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
*
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrap
{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul
{
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

ul li a
{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: @SenjutiMahapatra i trying to have the background the same color as the menu adn the background to be 100% :/

Comment: Do you wants `background` to strech to 100% of browser width when screen resolution is more than 960px i.e 1200px or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
*
{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#wrap
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul
{
    background: navy;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul li
{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width:11%;
}


    ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 20%;
    padding-bottom: 20%;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  

}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: is there a way to have the width of the menu(ul) to 960px

Answer (score 1):

Add a section as wrapper around it. And since you might want to re-use your `wrap` declare it as class.

### CSS:

```
#header {
  background: navy;
}

.wrap {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

ul {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<section id="header">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NnCVv/249/)**